# Solr Core Discovery mode defining extra properties

Tags: configuration, solr

We are upgrading to solr 4.4 and would like to be able to use the new core.properties for the new core discovery.

Currently, we have a couple of properties defined in the solr.xml for most of the cores, and I am not able to create these same properties in the new core.properties file.

Here is a core as currently defined in solr.xml:

```
<core name="core1003" instanceDir="core1003">
  <property name="xmlDataDir" value="D:\Solrfiles\ImportFiles\core1003.xml" />
</core>
```

This is then used in DIH-XPathEntityProcessor.xml with `<str name="xmlDataDir">${xmlDataDir}</str>`.

How can I define core specific property variables like this?  It doesn't necessarily have to be in core.properties, but that would make it a little easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

In your core instance directories that contain your core.properties file create a conf/ subdirectory and a solrcore.properties file in it. Define your core specific properties there and it will be picked up automatically.

Alternatively, you can add a value for "properties" to your core.properties file to point to any other file:

```
properties=/your/path/here.properties
```

I believe but have not confirmed that for this to work your cores must load on startup and must not be transient. Any non-standard properties you add to core.properties will be ignored because the CoreDescriptor copy constructor only persists the following properties from that file in memory: instanceDir, config, schema, name and dataDir (see CoreDescriptor:91 in the 4.4.0 source). I believe this is a bug?